# How to Customise only in blogger mobile Template (Check my questions please)

Tags: javascript

I am not using any custom 3rd party template. I have designed  some part according to my Requirements. Here is [**My Web URL**](http://www.achieversrule.com)

Requirements (Only For Mobile Template)

1. How to give Horizontal /seperation line after each posts in blogger mobile template only ?
2. In My website desktop view Each posts image has a border, but how can i show the same border in mobile view in front page.

Comment: I believe this is a CSS question.

Answer (score 1):

## for your first question, find this lines of code in your file :

```
html .mobile .mobile-date-outer, html .mobile .blog-pager {
    border-bottom: none;
    background: transparent none repeat scroll top center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

and add this line to it :

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
```

so it will be like this :

```
html .mobile .mobile-date-outer, html .mobile .blog-pager {
    border-bottom: none;
    background: transparent none repeat scroll top center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

## for your second question, add this styles into your page :

```
.mobile-index-thumbnail img {
    border: 3px solid #e6e6e6 !important;
}
```

Comment: I have one more problem - I am using "disqus" in my bogger. Here is the URL - www.achieversrule.com. In every posts, below that there is showing all comments named as "Also on: Achievers Rule" in that all comments section all comment title is same..... Current affairs I Bank I SSC .....    instead of my post title. How can i solve this big issues....